# What is a term-by-term explanation of Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I've been self-studying Fourier Transform for a while ("vanilla" transform, not FFT, DFT or other types of that sort) but I cannot seem to understand how the mathematical expression reflects the idea. Most sources that claim to be "intuitive" seem to recite similar ideas, like wrapping the function around a circle or representing functions as movements in circular patterns, etc. I kind of understand that process, but I cannot understand how it is reflected in the equation. I cannot understand the phrase " $$(e^{-2\pi(i)\alpha x})$$ represents wrapping the input wave function $f(x)$ around the origin of the complex plane at some frequency $\alpha$ " which has been shown [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/simple/Fourier_transform#:%7E:text=The%20Fourier%20transform%20is%20a,a%20wave%20is%20made%20of.&text=The%20output%20of%20a%20Fourier,possible%20frequencies%20of%20the%20input.), in particular. I know that at the heart of it lies [the Euler's formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Euler%27s_formula), which represents rotations with a given frequency.

How does it imply "wrapping"? How does this relate to the rest of the formula? I think my confusion is caused by notation, rather than the concept itself, but please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it comes to visualization $3$Blue$1$Brown is one of the best. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY&t=12s) he talks about the Fourier Transform and explains the idea of wrapping intuitively (Minute: 2:55). Also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gjJDuCAEQQ) video may give you a new perspective too.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I really like 3b1b but even his videos didn't help me this time. But the second video really helped me. What I get from it is that if you apply fourier transform to your signal of interest it kind of "resonates" proportionally in frequencies that are dominant in the signal, which is measured by integration. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. An example: In radians, we could describe a perfect A in the fourth octave with $\sin(2\pi\cdot440)$. If you plot the  FT of this sinusoid, you can see a spike at $440$, which shows the Hz of our tone A.